# How do I iterate to the next element in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to get the next element in a loop without starting from the beginning of the loop?

I know that `next` allows for iterating to the next element, but it starts at the beginning of the loop.  I want to get the next element and continue to the next statement in the loop.

I am parsing a text file that is structured as follows:

```
element 1
part 1
part 2

element 2
part 1
part 2
```

Note that there are eleven parts per element, so this is just an example. Also, sometimes there are lines that are stripped out during parsing, so I don't think I can advance by a fixed number of elements for each loop iteration.

I read all of the text into an array and then I want to process each line using something like:

```
text.each do |L|
  #if L is new element create object to store data
  #parse next line store as part 1
  #parse next line store as part 2
end
```

I know how to do this with a `while` loop and a C-like coding style where I explicitly index into the array and increment the index variable by the amount I want each time, but I'm wondering if there is a Ruby way to do this.  Something analogous to `next` but that would continue from the same point in the loop, just with the next element, rather than starting from the beginning of the loop.

---

Edit:

Here is a simplified example of how I could solve this problem with a `while` loop:

```
text = ["a", "b", "c", " ", " ", "d", "e", "f"]
i = 0
while i < text.length do
  if text[i] == " " then
    i += 1
  else
    a = text[i]
    b = text[i+1]
    c = text[i+2]
    puts a + b + c
    i += 3
  end
end
```

Note the actual code I'm writing is more complicated. I was trying to come up with the simplest example here that would illustrate what I want to do.

Comment: probably you could give an array and ask the question by demonstrating that array..

Comment: I'm unclear on the exact problem you are trying to solve. Perhaps you could supply the `while` version in Ruby or C to demonstrate?

Comment: @Confusion I am confused too.. :)

Comment: sorry the question is confusing. I'll try to clarify it.

Comment: @confusion or whoever downvoted the post please let me know if my edit helped clarify it.  Thanks.

Comment: I think that you may want to reconsider processing the data in a more functional—and less procedural—fashion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple. Change `each` to `each_with_index`, and use the index:

```
text.each_with_index do |L, i|
  #Get next element
  text[i + 1]
end
```

However, your specific problem has a much better solution. Use `each_slice`:

```
text.each_slice(num_of_parts_to_element + 1) do |element|
  element[0] #element 1
  element[1..-1].each do |part|
    #Iterate over the parts
  end
end
```

Comment: I have a doubt if this has been asked or not.. :)

Comment: will this let me skip over the lines that I've processed?  I.e. if I use `text[i+1]` in the loop then I don't want to have the next iteration of the loop work with that value?

Comment: @Linuxios still not correct.. :) if `num_of_parts_to_element` is not fixed for all cases...

Comment: @Babai: Quoting the question: "note there are 11 parts per element this is just an example"

Comment: @Linuxios OP could ask the question more better way.. :)

Comment: I should have been clearer in my question.  The number of elements is fixed when they are found.  But I also have some lines that I strip out during parsing.

Comment: @Gabriel: What do you mean "strip out during parsing"?

Comment: For example I remove blank lines (and some other cases). The code I used for blank lines is `next if L.chomp.empty?`

Comment: @Gabriel: Just remove those earlier. Before the loop, use `text.delete_if {|l| l.chomp.empty? || other_case || another_case}` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the suggestion of @Phrogz in the comments and running with it:

```
def handle_sequence(sequence)
  puts sequence.join
end

text = ["a", "b", "c", " ", " ", "d", "e", "f"]
sequences = text.split(" ")
sequences.reject! {|sequence| sequence.empty?}
sequences.each {|sequence| handle_sequence(sequence)}
```

I separated the `handle_sequence` into a method because I imagine you'll want to do something else than just concatenate and print the elements to stdout.

BTW, I didn't downvote, just asked for clarification